# inserting 0x00 into H2 embedded db binary(1) type column give "Value too long" error

Tags: spring, h2, mssql-jdbc

When I try to insert the value 0x00 into a column whose type is binary(1) I get the error:

`Value too long for column "SUMMARY VARBINARY(1)": "X'00000000' (4)";`

Why/how would the single byte 0x00 value get converted to a 4byte value?  This is in a test context and I want to use the column type (binary(1)) of the actual table.

This is with
H2 version 1.4.200;
Spring boot version 2.4.4;
mssql-jdbc: 8.4.1.jre8

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `MODE=MSSQLServer` to the jdbc-url property used in creating the HikariConfig bean which in turn is used in creating the HikariDataSource bean:

Specifically, in my application-test.properties I now have

`spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MSSQLServer`